# HDD in RDM in ESXi 6.0 really slow performance

Tags: vmware-esxi

I have a HDD configured as RDM in ESXi 6.0 and the drive transfer speeds are really slow.

Running a local tool, such as CrystalDiskMark, give normal speeds. But the transfer rate from it to a wired PC is slow. Im seeing 335 KB/s

The guest OS is Windows Server 2012 R2. The SCSI controller type is paravirtual.

A virtual hard drive (hooked to a seperate SCSI controller in ESXi) using LSI Logic SAS that is the system drive transfers perfectly and is not affected. This means that networking is not really involved in the problem.

Comment: Why do you have an RDM and your ESXi configured in this manner?

Comment: Why not? I can access S.M.A.R.T. information and also unplug the data drive, plug it into another system and I would see all my data...

Comment: What is your disk cue length on the target?

Comment: No disk quota on the target. Or are you talking about something else?